# Array of dictionaries: Add values if find identical in to single dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of structure like this

```
[["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "0", "name": "Ground turmeric", "unit": "teaspoons", "whole_quantity": "1"],
["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "", "name": "I", "unit": "cups", "whole_quantity": "1"],
["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "", "name": "I", "unit": "cups", "whole_quantity": "2"]]
```

Now, I want to find identical entries from ingredients that have the same key-value pair in that section and If found, want to add quantity into one and make one ingredient. You can check above array where the section name is "OTHER" and check ingredients there. I want to merge that 2 identical ingredients into a single one with quantity 1+1 = 2. So, the final result should be like

```
[["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "0", "name": "Ground turmeric", "unit": "teaspoons", "whole_quantity": "1"],
["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "", "name": "I", "unit": "cups", "whole_quantity": "3"]]
```

What I tried is loop here but I don't think its efficient way. So, Is there any better way to pull this thing off?

`My Code`

```
    guard let first = ingredients.first else {
        return [] // Empty array
    }

    var uniqueIngredients: [[String:String]] = [first] // Keep first element

    for elem in ingredients.dropFirst() {
        let equality = ingredients.compactMap { $0["name"] == elem["name"] }.count
        if equality > 1 {
            // SAME NAME FOR 2 INGREDIENT FOUND
            // COMBINE BOTH OBJECT
        } else {
            // NEW NAME
            // ADD NEW OBJECT
        }
   }
```

Comment: Why are you not using a struct/class instead of dictionary?

Comment: This is just basic idea right now. Even if I would use structure, logic will remain same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Group the array to a dictionary by `name`
- Create a variable `result`
- Enumerate the dictionary. If there is more than one item in `value` sum up the quantities and append only one item

The code assumes that the keys `name` and `whole_quantity` exist in all records and the value for key `whole_quantity` can be converted to `Int`

```
let array = [["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "0", "name": "Ground turmeric", "unit": "teaspoons", "whole_quantity": "1"],
             ["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "", "name": "I", "unit": "cups", "whole_quantity": "1"],
             ["grocery_section": "other", "partial_quantity": "", "name": "I", "unit": "cups", "whole_quantity": "2"]]

let groupedDictionary = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {$0["name"]!})
var result = [[String:String]]()
for (_, value) in groupedDictionary {
    if value.isEmpty { continue }
    else if value.count == 1 {
        result.append(value[0])
    } else {
        let totalQuantity = value.map{Int($0["whole_quantity"]!)!}.reduce(0, +)
        var mutableValue = value[0]
        mutableValue["whole_quantity"] = String(totalQuantity)
        result.append(mutableValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: One more suggestion please!! If partial quantity is like "1/2" and "1/4" in 2 elemets, how to make it like "0.75". I think I need to make function for that and than need to use map and reduce. Is it?

Comment: Yes, you need a mapping function which converts the fractions into decimals and the sum type has to be `Double`

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Let me try that out. And its a string so, I think I need to separate it by "/" and converts it into digits.

Comment: Sir one question. Is it possible to monitor clipboard in the background? Sorry, If its not right place to ask the question!!